# Is right diagonalizability equivalent to left diagonalizability?

Tags: diagonalization

I already know that, for a given complex square matrix, the right eigenvalues are also left eigenvalues, with same algebric multiplicity.

But what about geometric multiplicity?

I'm searching for a proof that, if the right eigenvectors form a basis, the same goes for left eigenvectors, but up till now I've found nothing.

Comment: In a finite-dimensional setting, the right eigenvectors are a basis iff the matrix vanishes a nonzero polynomial which is split and with simple roots. That condition is stable under transposition (which corresponds to considering left, instead of right, eigenvectors).

Comment: The Jordan normal form theorem can be used to show that a matrix is similar to its transpose, so the geometric multiplicities also match. This might be overkill, I don’t know.